# How to check a block if is realize？

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

In my code, if I use the block directly:

```
- (IBAction)checkPendingAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.block(sender.titleLabel.text);  // if the block is no realize, there will report EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=x, address=0x11xx)
}
```

If I use delegate, I can use the below code to check my delegate and delegate method if is realize:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myDelegateMethod:)]) {
    [self.delegate tabBarClickWriteButton:self];
}
```

So, can I check the block if is realize in iOS?

Comment: You can simply check if it is `nil`. `if (self.block != nil) { self.block(self.titleLabel.text); }`.

Comment: @Losiowaty Thank you, you can answer my question now.

Comment: Or just  **if (self.block) { self.block(self.titleLabel.text); }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check block as below

```
if (self.yourblock != nil) { 
    self.yourblock(self.titleLabel.text);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

make your block a property with 'strong' reference. and use weak reference of self in it if needed.

before calling block just check

if(block) {

block(data);

}